# Kendo UI - How do I capture only minutes and seconds for a date field in a grid?

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui

How do I send only minutes/seconds from Kendo UI Grid to a server api method that receives my row data for an update operation?

Using the following format I want hours to be zero and the model to receive minutes and seconds only, and not hours.

Is this possible?

EDIT

**WebApi update method**

```
public void Post(int id, [FromBody]Episode value)
{
    var episode = db.Episodes.Find(value.id);
    episode.DurationMinutes = value.DurationMinutes;
    episode.DurationSeconds = value.DurationSeconds;
    episode.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, value.DurationMinutes, value.DurationSeconds);  
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Database Model**

```
 public partial class Episode
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Duration { get; set; }
            public int DurationMinutes { get; set; }
            public int DurationSeconds { get; set; }
        }
```

**Kendo Column Array - This is where I am trying to "get" the values I posted but in my Kendo grid I get undefined!**

```
 var columns = [{
            field: "Duration",
            title: "Duration",
            template: "#= DurationMinutes + ':' + DurationSeconds #",
            width: 100
        },
        {
            field: "DurationMinutes",
            title: "DurationMinutes",
            width: 100,
            //hidden: true
        },
        {
            field: "DurationSeconds",
            title: "DurationSeconds",
            width: 100,
            //hidden: true
        }];
```

[image: Example Grid]

**Parameter Map Definition**

```
    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
        if (operation === "update") {
            var mm = data.Duration.split(':')[0];
            var ss = data.Duration.split(':')[1]; 
            data.DurationMinutes = mm;
            data.DurationSeconds = ss;
            return kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate way is to define your own [parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) function for the transport. The work-around would be to use the [dataSource.transport.update.data](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.update.data) function to modify the data object or add one more value to it which uses the format you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!  I appreciate it.  I got a suggestion from a colleague to use additional fields to capture minutes and seconds.  I made the change so now it is actually storing the field values.   The problem I face now is how to I "get back" the value from the two fields, minutes and seconds as a templated value in kendo.   I will post what I did for further clarification.

Comment: I have modified my original post.  I am now trying to get the new value in the same cell as a concatenation of two other cells (namely, DurationMinutes and DurationSeconds)

Comment: Turns out my C# LINQ query was missing the required extra columns.  After adding in the columns (fields) in the query I was able to retrieve the proper timespan values successfully!